# How can I replace a class if a new class appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to replace a class when a new class appears while dragging the div

```
<div class="grab-cursor">
```

changes to when user starts dragging the div

```
<div class="grabbing-cursor">
```

I have a accordion pane I need to close before the dragging completes

```
<div class"accordion_on">
```

want to change above to

```
<div class"accordion_off">
```

Comment: classes don't just *appear* - you need to show your javascript.

Comment: What are you using for dragging? jQuery-ui draggable?

Comment: its a gallery plugin not sure what part of the javascript adds the class, I was hoping since there is a condition available I could use that to update my styles

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski not jQuery-ui-draggable its a image gallery slider plugin

Answer (score 0):

using jquery:

```
$(".accordion_on").addClass("accordion_off").removeClass("accordion_on");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the class using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.my_draggable_elements').draggable({
    drag: function(){
      $('#'+this.id).attr('class','grabbing-cursor')
    }
});
```

});

You can also use javascript ondragstart and ondrop event to change the class

```
There are a number of different events to attach to for monitoring the entire drag and drop process:

ondragstart,ondrag,ondragenter,ondragleave,ondragover,ondragend,ondrop
```

call a function when dragging start

```
 ondragstart="change(this)"

function change(ev)
{
$('#'+ev.id).attr('class','grabbing-cursor');
}
```